# NSMutableArray add object from other array at index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, cocoa

Is there any way to do `addObjectFromArray:atIndex:`?

I have 2 NSMutableArrays. Lets say 1st array is `array1` and the 2nd is `array2`. They ar filled with values. And I need to add item from `array1` at index `3` to `array2`. Is it possible?

Comment: Does the index in array2 matter? Meaning: Do you want to have the object in array2 at the same index as in array1 (if possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrieve the object using:

```
[array1 objectAtIndex:3]
```

Add the object using:

```
[array2 addObject:theObject];
```

In other words, the following adds object `3` from `array1` to `array2`:

```
 [array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:3]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break this into two steps, like this:

```
[array2 addObject: [array1 objectAtIndex: index3]];
```

Answer (score 1):

We have `addObjectsFromArray:` method it means,adds the objects contained in another given array to the end of the receiving array’s content. 
But we don't have  `addObjectFromArray:atIndex`:  method. For getting your results, you can use methods what NSMutableArray class contains.

```
[array2 addObject: [array1 objectAtIndex: index3]];
```

Here we can use two methods `addObject:` and `objectAtIndex:`. For more details, use this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).